# How to make custom segue with left push effect?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, storyboard, uistoryboardsegue

My application is displaying **Arabic text** in which **i want push animation from left side and not from right side which ios provides by default.**

[image]

I am using **storyboards**.I have created **custom segue**. 

I have gone through all options [cocoacontrols](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/) but have not found desired one.

**I have found several options as follows:**

1) CATransition 
2) Animation    
3) maintaining view controllers array - which creates lot of mess

Below code gives perfect effect **but black patches as show below are not acceptable** -

[image]

```
-(void)perform {


UIViewController *sourceViewController = (UIViewController*)[self sourceViewController];
UIViewController *destinationController = (UIViewController*)[self destinationViewController];


CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.duration = .25;
transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
transition.type = kCATransitionPush; //kCATransitionMoveIn; //, kCATransitionPush, kCATransitionReveal, kCATransitionFade
transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft; //kCATransitionFromLeft, kCATransitionFromRight, kCATransitionFromTop, kCATransitionFromBottom




[sourceViewController.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:transition
                                                            forKey:kCATransition];

[sourceViewController.navigationController pushViewController:destinationController animated:NO];

[destinationController.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

}
```

**Implemented below code give no black patches - but not desired animation**

```
  -(void)perform {

 UIViewController *sourceViewController = (UIViewController*)[self sourceViewController];
 UIViewController *destinationViewController = (UIViewController*)[self destinationViewController];



[sourceViewController.view addSubview:destinationViewController.view];
[destinationViewController.view setFrame:sourceViewController.view.window.frame];
[destinationViewController.view setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.5,0.5)];
[destinationViewController.view setAlpha:1.0];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                      delay:0.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                 animations:^{
                     [destinationViewController.view setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0,1.0)];
                     [destinationViewController.view setAlpha:1.0];
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     [destinationViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
                     [sourceViewController.navigationController pushViewController:destinationViewController animated:NO];
                 }];

   }
```

By changing above code - **but i am not getting desired result**

```
-(void)perform{

UIViewController *sourceViewController = (UIViewController*)[self sourceViewController];
UIViewController *destinationViewController = (UIViewController*)[self   destinationViewController];



   [sourceViewController.view addSubview:destinationViewController.view];
   [destinationViewController.view setFrame:sourceViewController.view.window.frame];
   [destinationViewController.view setAlpha:1.0];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                      delay:0.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                 animations:^{

                     sourceViewController.view.frame =      CGRectMake(sourceViewController.view.frame.size.width*2, 0, sourceViewController.view.frame.size.width, sourceViewController.view.frame.size.height);



                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){


                     [sourceViewController.navigationController pushViewController:destinationViewController animated:NO];
                 }];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use below code In appDelegate.m - `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whitecolor];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a custom segue in swift that uses the messy way, manipulates list of view controllers.. Anyway, I wanted to push to a view controller, but make it look like it was a pop, and I tried to do it with all sorts of animations, but in the end - for me, this was the most simplest way to get what I wanted as I don't have to maintain my code, if iOS styling changes and so on, as it uses general pop - it should remain the same as default pop in the system.. Anyway, to the code:

```
class ReversePushSegue : UIStoryboardSegue {

    override func perform() {
        let sourceViewController = self.sourceViewController as UIViewController
        let destinationViewController = self.destinationViewController as UIViewController

        var vcs : NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray(array: sourceViewController.navigationController.viewControllers)
        vcs.insertObject(destinationViewController, atIndex: vcs.count - 1)
        sourceViewController.navigationController.viewControllers = vcs

        sourceViewController.navigationController.popViewControllerAnimated(true)

    }

}
```

What it does - it adds destinationViewController to the list as second last and then pops to it..